# Bash subshell: parentheses:() VS dollar-parentheses:$()

Tags: bash

In bash, both `()` and `$()` create a subshell.

What's the difference between each other? What's their typical usages?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`()` just creates a compound command, running the commands inside the parentheses.  `$()` does the same, but also substitutes the output.

From the docs:

1. **`(list)`**
   `list` is executed in a subshell environment ...  Variable assignments  and  builtin
             commands  that  affect the shell's environment do not remain in effect after the command completes.  The return status is
             the exit status of `list`.
2. **Command Substitution**
      Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command name.  There are two forms:

   ```
   $(command)
   ```

   or

   ```
   `command`
   ```

   Bash performs the expansion by executing `command` and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command,
      with any trailing newlines deleted.

Comment: An "aha" moment! "Command substitution" is how we are able to assign the output of a command to a variable, e.g. with `RESULT=$(command)`, the output of `$(command)` replaces the command and is then assigned to `RESULT`.