# File checking shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

A program that takes in a file as agument 1 and a time in seconds in argument 2, and then the program will check if:

1. The file exist
2. If file has been changed

.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
sleeptime=$2
bool=true

if [ -e $file ]; then
    thetime=$(date -r $file "+%s")
    newtime=$(date -r $file "+%s")
    while "$bool" = true
    do
        sleep $sleeptime
        newtime=$(date -r $file "+%s")
        if [ "$thetime" -ne "$newtime" ]; then
            bool=false
            echo "Filen $file ble endret"
        fi
        if [ ! -e $file ]; then
            bool=false
            echo "Filen $file ble slettet"
        fi
    done
fi
if [ ! -e $file ]; then
    while "$bool" = true
    do
        sleep $sleeptime
        if [ -e $file ]; then
            bool=false
            echo "Filen $file ble opprettet"
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: You should consult a bash reference on how `if` and `while` conditions work.

Comment: Please paste your code into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and address the errors and warnings that it will identify.  After that, if you still have problems or you don't understand its messages, then come to SO and ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is quite hard to get into, to give you a few pointers:

- subcommands in conditions are a somewhat tricky, you usually want to run it in a subshell with substitution if the expression contains variables, which is done by `$()`, not `()` ([explained in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462291/bash-subshell-parenthese-vs-dollar-parenthese?answertab=votes#tab-top))
- `while`, `if` needs to be separated from `do`, `then` either by a semicolon or by a newline
- [testing conditions in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html) is a bit different from other languages, in your case `-f` operator checks file is a regular file (see further [file testing operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html))
- it's usually better to quote variables in conditions and variables passed to commands for case they contain special characters (which would be evaluated otherwise)
- not sure what should be the nature of "file hasn't been changed" claim, but probably the simplest approach is to test if it's size changed, for a start the `-s` operator checks if size of a file is more than zero
- as it's pointed out in a comment application-specific variables should be lower-case by convention

Your code with these adjustments:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
sleeptime=$2
while ($(sleep $sleeptime)); do
   if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
      touch $file
      echo "File $file was created."
   elif [ ! -s "$file" ]; then
      rm $file
      echo "File $file was deleted."
   fi
done
```

Comment: Quoting is needed in arguments to `touch` and `rm`, not just to `[`. And see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html re: variable naming conventions (all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell or OS; lowercase names are guaranteed safe for application use).

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
sleeptime=$2
while :; do
    sleep "$sleeptime"
    if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
        if [ "$file" -nt ".tag.$file" ] ; then
            echo "Not removed $file, because it was changed"
        else
            rm "$file"
            rm ".tag.$file"
            echo "File $file was deleted."
        fi
    else
        touch "$file"
        touch ".tag.$file"
        echo "File $file was created."
    fi
done
```

Notes:

- cleaned-up some of the code.
- see `man test`.
- uppercase variables are usually used for environment variables.

Comment: Lots still broken here (missing quoting mostly). Could you try to get this to pass http://shellcheck.net/?

Comment: Quoting? I ran it on my linux-box and only a `;` was missing (sorry, I see it; I assumed `$file` does not have spaces in them)